# jsdom wait the requirejs call finish

Tags: requirejs, jsdom

I want to make e2e test on my site. In my site, I use requirejs to load necessary components.

I use jsdom.env(env, [jquery], function(error, window){....});

In the function, I use setInterval to block the assert until $.active is 0. But it is 0 at the beginning, it seems that the requirejs has never been called.

Is there another to block the assert until the requirejs call finished?

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS doesn't use jQuery to load the modules and that's why the counter stays at zero.

You can access `require.s.contexts._.defined` to see all the loaded modules. It's an object which has the module paths as keys and the modules themselves as values.

Alternatively, you could create a module that has all of the necessary components as dependencies and set some global variable in its definition.

```
define(['alpha', 'beta'], function() {
    window.alphaAndBetaLoaded = true;
});
```

Comment: You means that I can check the count of the loaded modules?

Comment: You means that I check count of the loaded modules? Can you explain this  detail in order I can get the count of the loaded modules by jsdom?

Comment: Use Object.keys(obj) which returns an array. Check the length of that.